REST API POST Only Fails When the Client Object is Reused & Only on Production Server in the Clients Network
For over a month, we had been creating a new HTTP client object for every POST request without encountering any issues. This, however, led to many open TCP connections, and the documentation suggests creating a single client object and reusing it for subsequent function calls. After refactoring to reuse a single client object, we've encountered random errors where data is not sent successfully.
Problem:
When the client object is created inside the POST function (client = system.net.httpClient()), everything works fine every time.
However, when we change it to reuse the client object (client = Utilities.client), it randomly fails to send data.
Troubleshooting:
We set up a test VM on our network running the same application, posting to the same server, and it never fails. It works whether we reuse the client object or create a new one each time.
The issue only occurs on the production server on the customer’s network, and only when trying to reuse the single client object. It seems like no data is being received by the database server when it fails.
Observations:
Using TCPView on both servers:
On the test VM, TCP connections open and close normally. The next time the function runs, a new connection is opened, and the data is always sent successfully.
On the production server, it often fails if the previous connection is still open when trying to send data again.
Using Wireshark:
On the test VM, everything looks normal with no retransmissions.
On the production server, I see several retransmitted TCP segment packets:
TCP    1434    [TCP Retransmission] 58667 → 443 [PSH, ACK] Seq=53970 Ack=6838 Win=261632 Len=1380
Eventually followed by a reset:
TCP    54  58592 → 443 [RST, ACK, CWR] Seq=34805 Ack=6838 Win=0 Len=0
Questions:
Network Differences: Could this be due to network configurations or firewalls in the customer's environment compared to our test setup? If so, what’s the best way to pinpoint the issue?
Connection Reuse: Could reusing a single client object be causing connection issues (i.e., the server might be closing or rejecting the connection due to it being open for too long)?
Wireshark Analysis: What would be the best way to interpret the retransmission and reset packets? Has anyone seen similar issues when reusing HTTP client connections?
Best Practices: Are there any recommended best practices for managing persistent HTTP clients in production, especially in cases where TCP connections might be reused or left open?
Any help or suggestions on what to check next would be greatly appreciated!

After more testing:
I did think that the TCP connection in TCPView was always there in the test VM but it was POSTing every minute at the time trying to see if it would ever fail, it still has not. It's now set to POST ever 10 minutes like production server is. Now on the test VM the TCP connection is closed 2 minutes after each POST but no POSTs fail.
I think I found a pattern.
On the production server the TCP connection is not closed after 2 minutes. Not sure why that is or if it matters. On the test VM the TCP connection is closed after 2 minutes but even if the POSTs are sent every minute before the TCP connection can close, it still works if the TCP connection is still there or not. On the production server, it seems to fail if the TCP connection is already there and it's been more than 2 minutes. I've been able to repeat this a few time now. If there is no current TCP connection, POST will be ok. If it is already there and it's been less than 2 minutes I can make as many POSTs as I want. After 2 minutes the POST will fail and then the TCP connection will close, then the next POST will work.
But...
On two different days now I've seen the data POST ever 10 minutes like it should overnight but then start to fail every other POST during the day. ??? Like once folks are on site and more active on the network is causing the POST to fail. But then why would creating the client every time always work? All failed POSTs stopped at 4:40pm just before I logged of and started again at 5:50am when their day starts again onsite. I was wondering if it was my RDP connection but I logged on at 8am.

I can see chrome for example only opens one channel. Dont know aboout .net sorry, my (rather light) client creates a WebClient() every time. Maybe do some tests with WebClient?

"On the test VM, TCP connections open and close normally" - if you observe chrome repeatedly loading the same XHR rest data, you will see it just uses one connection that remains "Established"

The script is running in an application that uses Python and the system.net.httpClient() is (I think) used in some kind of wrapper. Also, on two different days now I've seen the data POST ever 10 minutes like it should overnight but then start to fail every other POST during the day. ??? Like once folks are on site and more active on the network is causing the POST to fail. But then why would creating the client every time always work?
All failed POSTs stopped at 4:40pm just before I logged of and started again at 5:50am?
Should I have posted this on the Stack Overflow site?

You say "The next time the function runs, a new connection is opened, and the data is always sent successfully.", but didnt you say the intention was to not have new connections everytime? What is the error given by the object? Also if its 10mins between posts why not just make a new object.

The HMI manual and their support folks says to not recreate the client object for each POST. The client object has an error that it can not connect to the Azure server, (I think) because the stuck open TCP connection is there but not really. When the java.exe TCP connection is created it works but on the production system it is not closed after 2 minutes and the next POST request fails. When the connection is open, it works for two minutes. After 2 minutes the next POST will fail and then the connection is closed. It's all even weirder as the POSTs only fail during the day, from 5am-5pm or so.

sorry mate dunno. Doesnt sound like connection management nor pooling is working. If you are every 10mins, just recreate the object. I do.  2000 clients every minute.

The current theory is that a NAT gateway and/or stateful firewall is filling up its connection tracking table and removes the one opened by the Java.exe after a time of inactivity. Then by the time the Azure server sends the [FIN,ACK], the path back to the Ignition server is gone.
Maybe it happens consistently during the business day because the overall activity is higher with more connection in use.

Im using new WebClient every time (.net 3.5 tech). My netstat output only shows one or two connections.
